# How to access specific ports from external client

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps, port, port-forwarding

As a warning, this is a noob question, sorry in advance. I wanted to install beancount/fava on my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS - GNU/Linux 4.15.0-76-generic x86_64).

With SSH tunelling (with Putty), I managed to get access to port 5000 through localhost:5000, but I don't know how to allow the external client to access that without the SSH tunnel enabled (i.e. accessing http://IPofmyVPS:5000/ from any browser/computer). I tried to open port 5000 with iptables and ufw but no chance on that side.

Comment: what tells `lsof -i :5000`

Comment: @djdomi it tells: COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
fava    612 root    3u  IPv6  17220      0t0  TCP localhost:5000 (LISTEN)

Answer (score 1):

Actually ports were only listenig to 172.0.0 without listening to external adresses. Just had to install a reverse proxy to gain access to the port 5000 through web :)